# prove correctness of power algorithm using loop invariance

Tags: algorithm, math

[image]

The algorithm computes the pth power of x and stores the result in r. I see how it operates, but to me it seems that there would be two cases (for odd and even p). I can't find a loop invariant for this algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation regarding [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

Let p<sub>i</sub> and x<sub>i</sub> denote the values of the variables `p` and `x` respectively at the i<sup>th</sup> iteration of the loop, where p<sub>0</sub> and x<sub>0</sub> are the respective values of `p` and `x` when initially passed to the function. Let r<sub>i</sub> denote the value of the variable `r` at the i<sup>th</sup> iteration of the loop, and note that r<sub>0</sub> is 1, which happens to be (x<sub>0</sub>)<sup>0</sup> (x<sub>0</sub> raised to the 0<sup>th</sup> power).

The precondition is: p<sub>0</sub> ≥ 0

The invariant is: p<sub>i</sub> ≥ 0 and r<sub>i</sub>·(x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>p<sub>i</sub></sup> = (x<sub>0</sub>)<sup>p<sub>0</sub></sup>

First, prove the invariant with induction. Then, find a way to prove that the loop terminates.

When the loop terminates, there exists iteration n such that p<sub>n</sub> = 0. Thus, r<sub>n</sub> = (x<sub>0</sub>)<sup>p<sub>0</sub></sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Claim

```
r*x^p
```

is invariant in every step.

---

Note: The procedure should not compile, since it contains an implicit conversion `double` to `int` in the return value. Thus it also does not conform to its description.

Comment: no, p will vary between odd and even. x^13 = x^8.x^4.x^1. 8+4+ 1 = 13. Similarly, for x^12. The algorithm works differently for even and odd ps. Hence, the if condition. So, to prove it's correctness, how would I find a loop invariant that formulates a relationship between r,x and p. Please explain your answer, if you have one in a little more detail, if it's not too much trouble. I am relatively new at this.

Comment: It is `r*x^p=(r*x)*^(p-1)` for odd `p` and `r*x^p=r*(x^2)^(p/2)` for even `p`.